# Change color of selected multiselect items

Tags: html, css, select, colors, multi-select

I have a `multiple select` element on the page:

```
<select multiple="multiple">
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
  <option>Three</option>
</select>
```

Its options color is black. But when I select an option, its color becomes white.

How can I change color of selected option to black (or some other color I want) with css?

I tried using

- `select option:active`
- `select option:checked`
- `select option:focus`
- `select option:hover`

but they don't do the trick.

UPD:
here is the jsfiddle of what I need: https://jsfiddle.net/htshame/th3gesvv/4/

Comment: @Pete there isn't much code here, if I've understood you correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to achieve this **only in CSS** but I know that you can select the *selected* option using CSS.

My suggestion is to use jQuery to update the attribute of the *selected* option and then change the CSS rule `[selected]` to put your preferred background color.

Here is a running example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('select').change(function() {
   var selectedOption = $(this).find(':selected');
   selectedOption.attr('selected','selected');
}).change();
});
```

```css
select{height: 200px; width: 300px;}
option {margin: 10px;}

[selected] {
    background-color: #0f0;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple">
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
  <option>Three</option>
  <option>Four</option>
  <option>Five</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That's not quite the behavior I need. I want option color to be black when it is currently selected.

Comment: and you can't get it by doing `[selected] {background-color: #000;}` ?

Comment: Your code does the following: I select the option (background color is dark-blue, options text color is white); I select another option (this options background color is dark blue and this options text color is white), but the background of previous options becomes green.  I want the following behavior: when I select the option (and while it's selected) it's background shold remain dark-blue as it is, and options text color should be black (or some other color), but now it is white.

Comment: when I change to `[selected] {background-color: #000;}`  the background-color just becomes black, but not the text of the option.

Comment: I've updated my question with jsfiddle, where alert tells when I need the color to be black.